# How to print a list of tuples without commas in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in python.

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and a third list `c` that is the `zip` of them.

```
c = zip(a, b)
```

or simply I have a list of tuples like this:

```
c = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (4, 2), (8, 3), (16, 4)]
```

I would like to print the list `c` without the commas after the parentheses. Is there a way to do this in Python?

I would like to print the list `c` like this:

```
[(1, 0) (2, 1) (4, 2) (8, 3) (16, 4)]
```

Comment: just curious as to why you want to do this?

Comment: Because I am using `tikz` in LaTeX to plot graphs. The outputs that I am getting are generated in Python, i.e., list of tuples. If I print them normally `print(list)`, I will have to remove all the commas to write the printed list in `tikz` since `tikz` does not accept a set of points like this `(0, 0), (1, 1)`. When the list is very long, I would not want to start removing the commas one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print('[%s]' % ' '.join(map(str, c)))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 0) (2, 1) (4, 2) (8, 3) (16, 4)]
```

for your inputs.

You can basically take advantage of the fact that you're using the natural string representation of the tuples and just join with a space.

Answer (score 3):

```
print('[' + ' '.join([str(tup) for tup in c]) + ']')
```

Using a list comprehension to create a list of the tuples in string form. Those are then joined and the square brackets are added to make it look as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be okay to create the final result as a string?

```
c_no_comma = ''
for element in c:
    c_no_comma += str(element) + ' '

c_no_comma = '[ ' + c_no_comma + ']'
```

Comment: This creates 2 new string objects for every element in the list then 2 more at the end, plus the one you started with. Terribly inefficient.